# developer console doesn't show my google apps script projects

Tags: google-apps-script, google-signin

I'm trying to create a google apps script project where is required to access by anyone (people with google account) and executed by the same user (user accessing the web app). I've published the app as "web app" and it work with the given url.

Since i need to this web app as a web service using ajax, the browser console return an error of unauthorised access (No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'x' is therefore not allowed access.) this doesn't happen if the web app is published as "Executed by my" and "access by anyone, even anonymous"

anyway,  i'm following the instructions in Google Sign-In for Websites and it said i need to access in google developer console to get credential for the project but my google apps script are not displayed in the project list.

Comment: I think you have to access it directly from the script itself, somewhere in project properties or in one of those menu tabs is a link to the developer console that is linked to the script.

Comment: that is true, i didn't notice about that. many thanks. the project is associated but still not displayed but at least i can assign to a different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open up the script, go to Resources > Developer Console Project > click on the link attached to the script.

Comment: but WHY does it not show up in my developer console? And to make it even more confusing, it opens it in "my" developer console, but nowhere does it say which project it is (except for having the project id in the url in the location bar). The **Select a Project** menu gives no indication you are on a project not in the list. Google App Script development should poperly be called Kafka's World of Bits of Javascript.

Comment: @Gerneio any idea where they moved the Resources button now?